# Consider the following change of basis matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the $n$ dimensional vector space $\mathbb{V}$ over the reals with two basis $B$ and $B'$. Show that the transition matrix maps coordinate vectors of the basis $B'$ to coordinate vectors in $B$.

I understand that the transition matrix, $P$ from $B$ to $B'$ is given by

$ b_{j}'=\sum ^{n}_{i=1}p_{ij}b_{i} $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we take a bases of the subspace $\mathbb{V}$ $\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...\}$, what you have to demonstrate is that the transformed base $\{\alpha'_1,\alpha'_2,...\}$ under the change of variables is a base. If the set of vectors $\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...\}$ is a base, I can always write the coordinates with respect to these vectors. meaning that $\alpha_1=(1,0,0,...)$, $\alpha_2=(0,1,0,...)$,... If you apply your expression for the change of variable
$$ \alpha_{1}'=P·\alpha_{1}=(P(1,1),P(2,1),P(3,1),...) \\
 \alpha_{2}'=P·\alpha_{2}=(P(1,2),P(2,2),P(3,2),...), $$
being P the matrix that transforms from one base to the other. Then, the transformed base $\{\alpha'_1,\alpha'_2,...\}$ will be formed by the columns of the transformation $P$. As the columns of the matrix are linearly independent ($\mbox{det}(P)\ne 0$) they are linearly independent and constitutes a base of $B'$. I hope it might solve your question!